# Width of PDF file is less that iPad screen, what should do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I tried to display Pdf file in UIWebView like this:                                               1.Take one UIwebView (name:pdfView). 2.Give Iboutlet connection to it & Delegate it to FilesOwner 3.In Viewdidload

[self.pdfView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ObjC" ofType:@"pdf"]]]];

4.ObjC.pdf should be in resource folder..                                                      Its working fine but when this file displays on view in runtime on iPad it shows simulator screen on right side. Means,, pdf is by default left alinged so that in right side it shows simulator screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`[self.pdfView setScalesPageToFit:YES];`

Comment: ok thanks a lot !!!                                                    I also find another way to set this property in IB.                     Just open respective .xib file then go to inspector of UIwebView then web view attributes and there tick mark scales page to fit option.

Comment: Glad to help u. Please push up arrow in the left of my answer.